# How to remove commas at the end of array elements if present?

Tags: perl

I have an array23 which contains strings of a file each in one line . Some strings have a "," in the end without a white space . I want to remove commas in the end of strings if they are present . I have tried the following code but is not working

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


open my $abcd , '>','perl_script_3_out_1.txt' or die $!;

foreach( @array23 )
 {
   if ((substr $_,0,-1) =~ ",")
   { 
    s/","//g;
   }
 }
  print $abcd  "$_";                                                                                                                                 

close($abcd);
```

Comment: The `print $abcd  $_,"\n"` should be inside the foreach loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program will not print anything as it stands, because your print statement (which is outside of your loop) refers to the [default variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) `$_`, which only exists in your loop.

You are also performing a regex on `","` - which is not what you want (`,` at the end of each string).

You should **always** add `use strict` and `use warnings` to the beginning of every script to catch this sort of thing

I would use something like this:

This only removes `,` that occur at the end of each line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $element (@array){
     $element =~ s/,$//g;
     print "$element\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @fugu the one you provided is working fine :) .I'll really appreciate if you could also tell where I went wrong .

Comment: The quotation marks in your pattern match aren't doing what you think they are.

Comment: I tried mine with  s/\,//g instead of s/","//g  also still its not working !

Comment: @Grace90: There's a few things wrong with your own code.  1. The format for `substr` is `substr EXPR,OFFSET,LENGTH` and you use `substr $_, 0, -1` so the offset is zero and the length is -1. A negative length removes that many characters off the end of the string, so you're deleting the character that might be a comma.  2. `s/","//g` deletes all occurrences of `","` when you want to remove just commas. `s/,//g` is correct, but  it will remove all commas anywhere in the string instead of just at the end.  3. You print the value of `$_` after the end of the loop when it no longer has any value.

Comment: @Sobrique ...working now ,had to put   print $abcd $_,"\n"  inside foreach loop as suggested by JE SUIS CHARLIE above  and  use   s/\,//g instead of s/","//g as you said . Thankyou :)

Comment: @Grace90: You don't need to escape the comma. `s/,//g` is fine. And your call to `substr` is also wrong.

Comment: @borodin thanks its working with or without escape :)